# How to point tablespace in Oracle's pre-built Developer Day VM to another mount point

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, storage

I have downloaded and started up Oracle's pre-built OTN Developer Day VM. The VM is running on an SSD. I want to load some data for development purposes. I am planning to create a new user and load the data under this new user's schema.

I would like to keep this data outside the SSD. I already have a mount point to an HDD inside the VM (as a network share). This mount point is a Samba share from another VM in the same machine.

My question is, how do I create a tablespace for the datafiles on this HDD mount point?

It would be nice if I can point undo and temporary tablespaces also to the HDD mount point.

My objective is to keep the VM size as low as possible.

I will appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I am thinking that instead of creating a new tablespace, why not move the existing tablespace/datafiles to the new vmdk. Looks like I can use the instructions in [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_move_datafiles.htm)

This is a development machine so optimizing for performance is not necessary. But, I will have data for multiple projects on it -- which is the reason I want to keep the data on the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

#### NFS

I highly recommend you change your design to use a supported file system : [NFS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/file-system-options-for-oracle-database.html#GUID-B4280399-263C-43A1-A944-0D47337FA711).

The database can use its own NFS client driver (Direct NFS) to talk to the NFS Server.  It will use the OS's if it can't use DNFS.

#### UNDO/TEMP

I'd keep these on the SSD and set `AUTO EXTEND` to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer left in a comment by [Phil](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/5555/phil%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9):

You can't create Oracle data files on SMB mounts, I'm afraid. Best way of doing it would be to add a new virtual disk to the Oracle VM, with the virtual disk files (vmdk, or whatever) on the other HDD.